# (Diff. Eq.) When solving homogeneous equations with constant coefficient, what if my auxiliary roots contain both real numbers AND complex roots?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here's an example. I'm asked to solve for $y'''+y''-2y=0$.

First, I set up an auxiliary equation $m^3+m^2-2=0$, and find that the roots are $m = 1, -1 \pm i$.

I'm stuck since we have BOTH real roots and complex roots. In this situation, what would be the formula that I plug into?

Comment: Yes, edited. Thanks!

Comment: All you need to remember is that you can "change formulas" for each pair of conjugate roots, in the sense that $\operatorname{span}_\mathbb{C}(e^{(a+ib)x}, e^{(a-ib)x}) = \operatorname{span}_\mathbb{C}(e^{ax}\cos(bx), e^{ax}\sin(bx))$, so it's fine if you have a mix of real and complex roots.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)
$$e^{(a+bi)x}=e^{ax}(\cos  (bx)+i\sin(bx))$$
Then the solution is:
$$y=c_1e^x+e^{-x}(c_2 \cos x +c_3\sin x)$$